# What does "5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1" refer to?

Tags: package-management, kde

I am a newbie on Ubuntu. I want to install the KDE 5.5 theme on Ubuntu 16.04.1. For that, I need to install a ton of dependencies. One of the packages I needed to install was libkf5prison1. While installing that, I got an error message saying

> libkf5prison1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.6.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1 is to be installed

Normally, when such an error comes, I simply prefix the required package by `sudo apt-get install` and it works. However, when I do `sudo apt-get install 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1` I do not find any valid package. How do I solve this problem?

Edit:

```
libkf5prison1:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.2+p16.04+git20160726.1358-0
  Version table:
     1.2.2+p16.04+git20160726.1358-0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ci/stable/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.2~git20150223-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
libqt5core5a:
  Installed: 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1
  Candidate: 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: This is a version specification. Please add the output of `apt-cache policy libkf5prison1 libqt5core5a` to your question.

Comment: You did `sudo apt-get install 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1` or `sudo apt-get install libqt5core5a=5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1`?

Comment: The first one, ie `sudo apt-get install 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1`. Upon running the second command it says that the package is already installed.

Comment: @RohanSaxena That's not the command you supposed to be running to resolve conflict. That's just a package version !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> libkf5prison1 : Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.6.0~beta) but 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1 is to be installed

This error says you need `libqt5core5a` package with version greater than or equal to `5.6.0~beta`, but the version `5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1` is needed to be installed. The need can be because of lack of higher version or dependency of some other package. In your case, from your `apt-cache policy libqt5core5a` output, it's apparent that, you don't have required version `>= 5.6.0~beta`

From your other output of `apt-cache policy libkf5prison1` It seems you're using [Kubuntu CI Stable](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ci/+archive/ubuntu/stable) PPA, which in their front page puts this Notice in BOLD types

> DO NOT USE THIS UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING.

That's it. The PPA has a package of higher version and it doesn't all the other higher versions of packages required by the first one. I recommend not using that PPA. however, if you still need to install the theme, you need to find other sources that provide the required version.

The exact string is part of the version of the package.

---

**De-construction of version number 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.1**

In this version number,

- `5.5.1+dfsg` is the *upstream version*. That is the version from the application developer.
- `16ubuntu7.1` is the *debian revision*. This also includes the *ubuntu modification version*.
- `ubuntu7.1` in `16ubuntu7.1` is the *ubuntu modification version* for a particular debian version.

Check [Ubuntu Policy Manual](http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/ubuntu-policy/policy.html/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) for a detail discussion about it.